# Django: Calling another modules function passed through a parameter

Tags: django, parameters, function, module

I have a list of functions as:

```
FUNCS=[{'someattr':'somedetail', 'func':baseapp.module.function_name}, {...}, ...]
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work if i try calling the func with

`FUNCS[0]['func']`

I get the error

`Tried function_name in module baseapp.module Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'function_name'`

I presume there must be something i'm missing with how python finds functions because the following does work:

```
   In [11]: def localfunc():
   ....:     print 'hi there'
   ....:     return

   In [13]: f=[{'func':localfunc}]

   In [16]: f[0]['func']()

   hi there
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Does it work if you add `import baseapp.module.function_name` to the top of your .py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution.

```
i = __import__('baseapp.module')
m = getattr(i,'module')
return m.function_name
```

thanks for the help